Is there an extension to this property of Kronecker products?
Fact: $$AXB = C \implies (B^T \otimes A)\text{vec}(X) = \text{vec}(C).$$
Now, let $A_1, A_2$ be symmetric, invertible matrices. This leads to a very useful identity (numerically), $$(A_1^{-1} \otimes A_2^{-1})x = y$$ being equivalent to $$A_2^{-1} \text{fold}(x) A_1^{-1} = \text{fold}(y).$$
This means that I won't have to calculate and store a big matrix $(A_1^{-1} \otimes A_2^{-1})$. I'm wondering if there exists a generalization for this identity, or at least for the three factor case. Suppose that $A_2 = (A_3 \otimes A_4) \implies A_2^{-1} = (A_3^{-1} \otimes A_4^{-1})$, and the result above would be $$(A_3^{-1} \otimes A_4^{-1}) \text{fold}(x) A_1^{-1} = \text{fold}(y).$$ I don't have an idea on what to do to avoid computing $A_3^{-1} \otimes A_4^{-1}$.
Edit: This is answered in the general form here.

@JeanMarie what? They're opposite operations.

Ah, I understand now...

If you're willing to work with 3D tensors, then yes such an identity exists

The product you're calculating could potentially be framed in terms of tensors. Suppose that $A_3$ and $A_4$ have shapes $m$ and $n$ respectively and that $A_1$ has size $\ell$. The computation corresponding to this product can be presented as
$$
\left[(A_3^{-1} \otimes A_4^{-1}) \text{fold}(x) A_1^{-1} \right]_{(n(i-1) + j, k)} = \\
\sum_{p = 1}^m \sum_{q = 1}^n\sum_{r = 1}^\ell 
[A_3^{-1}]_{(i, p)}[A_4^{-1}]_{(j,q)}[\operatorname{fold}(x)]_{(n(p-1) + q, r)} [A_1^{-1}]_{(r,k)},
\\
1 \leq i \leq m, \quad 1 \leq j \leq n, \quad 1 \leq k \leq \ell.
$$
Incidentally, then entries of $\text{fold}(x)$ are given by
$$
[\operatorname{fold}(x)]_{(n(p-1) + q, r)} = x_{\ell(n(p-1) + q) + r}.
$$
With that established, let $\text{F}(x)$ denote the 3-dimensional array (i.e. order-3 tensor) for which
$$
\text{F(x)}_{(p,q,r)} = [\operatorname{fold}(x)]_{(n(p-1) + q, r)} = x_{\ell(n(p-1) + q) + r}.
$$
We can then express the sum more straightforwardly as the tensor contraction
$$
{[A_3^{-1}]^{i}}_p{[A_4^{-1}]^{j}}_q {[A_1^{-1}]^{r}}_k{[\text{F}(x)]^{p,q}}_r,
$$
where each of the matrices $A_i$ is interpreted as a type $(1,1)$ tensor and $\text{F}(x)$ is a type $(2,1)$ tensor.
